# Field status need to select dynamically from child to parent object

Tags: trigger

RE: Here Opportunity and section are in master detail relationship.

Section status is a picklist field in section object with values are'1-won','2-In-market','3-Won/Mandated','4-Issued Commitments','5-Pipeline','6-Proposal Pending Risk Appr','7-Proposal Early Stage' Requirement scenarios

1. Opty got too many sections
2. Need to show in opty record with section status picklist value(i.e, based on priority) eg: from section records descending order value need to pick from section status and update in opty. suppose that record gets deleted then next descending order value need to be update in opty. For this I created a statusupdate custom field in Opty.

help me for coding logic like querying and update functionality.

for this just give idea like how to map with opty and section and querying and update functionality.. –

Comment: Please spend some time formatting the question so it's easier to read. At the moment it's wall of text (no linebreaks), hard to see what are you asking for. Looks like you've just copied some email with requirements and expect magic to happen. What have you tried so far to solve this requirement? Do you struggle with some piece of code?

Comment: for(Opportunity op: opty){
     if(lastmodifiedtn.containskey(op.id)){
        op.Latest_Section_Status__c = lastmodifiedtn.get(op.id).Section_Status__c;
     }
    else{
    op.Latest_Section_Status__c= null;
    }
}
update Opty;

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
trigger StatusRollup on Section__c(after insert, afert update, after delete, after undelete){
    Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Collect Ids of all opps to recalculate
    for(Section__c s : trigger.new){
        opportunityIds.add(s.Opportunity__c);
    }

    // Fetch the Opps with the last, "most mature" section as related list item
    List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Name, 
        (SELECT Status__c FROM Sections__r ORDER BY Status__c DESC LIMIT 1)
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds];

    // loop through them and update if needed
    for(Opportunity o : opps){
        if(o.Sections__r.isEmpty()){ // somebody deleted last Section?
             o.Section_Status__c = null;
        } else {
             o.Section_Status__c = o.Sections__r[0].Status__c;
        }
    }
    update opps;
}
```

Note that this blindly updates all opps (even if status would stay the same and there would be no point updating). I'm lazy ;)

---

You probably can achieve something similar with rollups (but they can't do MAX(SomePicklistField__c) so workarounds with numerical values stored on a side, maybe formulas or workflow updates would be needed... Might be not worth the effort.